# Output of getSystemClipboard().getString() is not right... (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard

I highlight text by mouse and press Shift to show a form containing a string from clipboard.

My event pressing shift sends virtual keys (Ctr+C), then I call the function windowsclickandsee() to get highlighted text from clipboard. 
But it's wrong.

For example:

In my clipboard already has a string - ("1234").

Step 1: i choose a text - ("hello") and highlight it.

Step 2: i press shift

**Result :**

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)` is `"1234"` and pressing ctr V, i see `"hello"`.

I dont understand. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code

```
    private void windowsclickandsee() 
    {         
      Platform.runLater(() -> {                                                         
          try {                 
              root = new StackPane();
              text= new TextArea();                                                                     
              String temp = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                      .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);                
              root.getChildren().add(text);
              text.appendText("1 "+temp);
              Point p= MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
              Scene scene = new Scene(root,400, 350);
              primaryStage.setScene(scene);
              primaryStage.setX(p.x);
              primaryStage.setY(p.y);
              primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
              primaryStage.show();
          } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Jnativehook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Jnativehook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }        
      });         
    }
```

Comment: Is this a mixed JavaFX and AWT/Swing application? If not, you should use JavaFX API for this... not AWT API. E.g. `Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString()`.

Comment: I have tried as you said, but it doesnt change anything. The result is wrong